# I want to fetch 2 records with same id

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
Id  user_id   Name
--- --------  ------
1      1        A
2      1        B
3      1        C
4      2        D
5      2        E
6      2        F
```

This is my user table and i want to fetch 2 rows in descending using user_id.
I want output like.

```
Id  user_id   Name
--- --------  ------
2      1        B
3      1        C
5      2        E
6      2        F
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please provide some of your attempts to solve your question.

Comment: I am using php mysql

Comment: I try this but i can't understand this query
SELECT  *
FROM (
SELECT *,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = permission_id THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:=permission_id
FROM role_has_permissions
  CROSS JOIN(SELECT @g:=NULL ,@r:=0) t
  ORDER BY permission_id desc
) c
WHERE c.rownum <=2

Comment: What version of **MariaDB** are you using?

Comment: Server version: 10.1.35-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you strictly need an ANCIer approach. You should try below co-related sub query -

```
SELECT Id, user_id, Name
FROM  T T2
WHERE (SELECT  COUNT(*)
       FROM    T T3
       WHERE T2.user_id = T3.user_id
       AND T2.Id <= T3.Id) <= 2
```

[Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=be35be845de2bea6cb5c91cca9defeb8)

Comment: It's return empty result

Comment: You can check the fiddle. Its working absolutely fine. You may change the sample data as per your requirement and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Why you unaccepted this answer. Doesn't this answer solve your problem?

Comment: No Because when i add another 2 records with user id 1 then there are showing 4 records of user 1 and i want to only two records of every user id.

Comment: please add 2 record with user_id 1 in fiddle and check what happens

Comment: @Pranjal, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=098e4d8e07bff1ce7c7cab3bc1964fe4 is the updated fiddle. Please check.

Comment: @Pranjal, I have more simplified the query. Please try the edited version.

Comment: it's also working perfectly, Thanks man. You know yii2 i need one help in yii2

Comment: You can post that as a new question with tag YII. Someone expert in YII will surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select Id, user_id, Name
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
order by user_id, id
```

Comment: SQL query: Documentation


select Id, user_id, Name
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
order by user_id, id LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by user_id order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where' at line 2

Comment: @Pranjal: then you are using an outdated MySQL version which doesn't support modern SQL

Comment: This is MariaDB, not MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for the suggestion but i need solution in this sql version

Comment: @Pranjal: then you are using and outdated MariaDB version that doesn't support modern SQL: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions-overview/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know I am using outdated mariadb version but at this stage of my project i can't changes in mariadb so if you have any solution with my current version then please give.